# setScrollX method doesn't work same with different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-imageview, scale, android-view, android-screen-support

I found that `setScrollX` doesn't work in the same way in different screen sizes. But the scale method `setScaleX` works the same in different devices (I mean it shows the same scaled image). How can I get the same result from `setScrollX` in different android phones or tablets?

I used this methods for an `ImageView` and actually I want to zoom to an `ImageView` and then scroll on it.

```
ImageView mainImage = findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.mainImg);
mainImage.setScaleX(6);
mainImage.setScaleY(6);
mainImage.setScrollX(200);
mainImage.setScrollY(200);
```